# react isomirphic-fetch promise chaining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Okay, as I understood the promise chain works as you keep returning promise inside previous promise response function:

```
SomePromise.then(function(response){
  return anotherPromise(response.data); <- Promise returning function
}).then(function(response){
  return yetAnotherPromise(response.data); <- Promise returning function
}).then(function(response){
   ItIsDone(response.data);
}).catch(function(err){
  someErrorHandling(err);
});
```

if any of the promise returning function would be remove the chain would no continue. And yet today it proved me wrong when i did this in react with isomorphic-fetch.

Inside auth service;

```
login: function (email, password) {

    let promise = fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/login', {
        method : 'POST',
        body   : JSON.stringify({email, password}),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });

    promise.then(function (res) {
        if (validator.IsJson(res))
            return res.json();
    }).then(function (parsedData) {
        if (parsedData.access_token !== undefined)
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', parsedData);
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('it is crazy');
    });

    return promise;
},
```

Inside app:

```
login(){
    auth.login(this.state.email, this.state.password).then(() => {
        NotificationManager.success('Successful login');
    }).catch((err) => {
        NotificationManager.error(err.message);
    });
}
```

In case of an error (if the response is not json) the token should not be saved because the res.json() function is not returned, thus causing the chain to stop. Yet the line "it is crazy" is Always printed out, why?

Comment: Forgot to mention the goal: It was to return promise for notification handling while the service should handle the token storing.

Comment: Return nothing is return `undefined`, then `undefined` is passed to next `.then`, in your code, parseData is now `undefined`. Please add the goal to question itself, not leave it as comment.

Comment: But I am not returning anything hte validator.IsJson(res) -> returns false. It automatically return undefined?

Comment: Yes, it returns `undefined` if you didn't specify the return value, and to correct, `.then` returns a `Promise`, it'll be resolved/rejected to the value in its callback, if the return value in the callback is a promise, it'll be resolved by the returned promise's resolve value, or reject if the returned promise get rejected. So, as long you attach another `.then`, the promise chain keep continues to the end.